# couchDB startkeys from specific date

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchDB view format like:

```
"map": "function(doc) { emit([doc.uid, doc.timestamp], doc._id); }"
```

And I want to query by the uid with timestamp. (timestamp is epoch format)

```
_http://url_to_CouchDB/DB/_design/query/_view/view?startkey=[uid1,1405485278284]&endkey=[uid1,{}]
```

However, the timestamp I put in the startkey seems being ignore and the view output is the same without specifying timestamp.

What I want is to query the view by before the timestamp, so that I don't have to return all doc_id at once.

p.s. uid here is the user id I want to query to. The function here is to find all the post of a user by the time stamp.

Thanks

Comment: What you are doing is correct. This could probably be a problem in the key ranges that you are passing. Are you sure you are passing in right timestamp in start key?

Comment: I query as the example I shown above, but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

What is the selectivity like for `doc.uid`;  is it different for every document?  If so, then your view will be generally insensitive to the timestamp.  Consider

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.timestamp], null);
}
```

note also that you don't need to include the `doc._id` explicitly in the mapped results, it's always present in the result for un-reduced queries.

Comment: uid is user id that I want to query. So this function is to print out all the `doc._id` for a user by `uid`.